# Javascript code bugs other code

Tags: javascript, html

Is there something wrong with this code? 
Because the rest of my js code only work if I delete it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value };


});
</script>
```

This code doesnt work when I use the one above.

```
<script>
var url1 = "http://192.168.1.157/wp/";
var url2 = "http://192.168.1.157/wp/parceiros";
var url3 = "http://192.168.1.157/wp/contato";

$(function(){
if (location.href==url2) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#bluecontent").offset().top }, 1500);
    });
}
else {
}
if (location.href==url3) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#allcontentcontact").offset().top }, 1500);
    });
}
else {
}
});
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `#uploadBtn` and `uploadFile` on the page? Check your console for errors.

Comment: Could you display more relevant source code *html* please?

Comment: try jquery to bypass missing elements:
    $("#uploadBtn").change(function () {$("#uploadFile").val(this.value) })

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

The problem is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value };


});
</script>
```

This code was on header, and for some reason it only works (without hurting the other js codes) when it's inserted on the page that contains `#uploadBtn` and `#uploadFile`.